# Python Selenium Webdriver: Enumerate hyperlinks and download files

Tags: python, selenium, download, webdriver, enumeration

I'm trying to enumerate all hyperlinks (with files to download from) from a webpage, and subsequently download these files one after the other. The hyperlinks when clicked require a form to be filled for which I've created a class to complete the same. I receive "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'click'" during the run  of the code. I've hereby attached the code, any suggestion to rectify this will much appreciated.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DatG_Py_Dat")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower')

assert "resources" in driver.title
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
z = elem

for links in enumerate(z):
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    for link in enumerate(links):
        link.click()


        class FormPage(object):
            def fill_form(self, data):
                driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-download-reasons-non-commercial').click()")
                driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-reasons-d-rd').click()")
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
                return self

            def submit(self):
                driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-submit').click()")


        data = {
            'name_d': 'xyz',
            'mail_d': 'xyz@outlook.com',
        }

        time.sleep(3)
        FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your usage of enumerate, which is plainly wrong.
Given

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
```

you can now simply iterate over this collection, such as:

```
for link in elem:
    link.click()
```

All the rest you do not need.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying Andreas. Although now I receive an assertion error while running the code, I did inspect the page source before including the "resources" in the driver.title. Am I missing out on something here?

Comment: I simply commented that line, as I was not sure what your intention with the assert was. Please clarify your intention if this is a feature.

Comment: Hi Andreas, The intention is to locate and download all xml links in the webpage. I've updated the code now, but face issue with CSS selector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784644/python-selenium-css-selector-element-is-not-visible