# Python Selenium CSS Selector: Element is not visible

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver, visibility

I want to locate all the hyperlinks in a webpage which has a xml download link and download them in a loop. 
There is form which arises when the said hyperlink is clicked, and needs to be filled to proceed with the download. 
I'm facing issues in the visibility of the elements related to this xml files in the webpage, but I receive the following error:

> "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
>   Element is not visible"

I've hereby attached the code, any suggestions to rectify this will be much appreciated.

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "F:\Projects\Poli_Map\DatG_Py_Dat")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/xml")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

m = 'xml'
driver.get('https://data.gov.in/catalog/variety-wise-daily-market-prices-data-cauliflower')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
elem.send_keys("xml")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-recent-events li")))

assert m in driver.page_source
for link in elem:
    link.click()


    class FormPage(object):
        def fill_form(self, data):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-download-reasons-non-commercial').click()")
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-reasons-d-rd').click()")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
            return self

        def submit(self):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-submit').click()")


    data = {
        'name_d': 'xyz',
        'mail_d': 'xyz@outlook.com',
    }

    time.sleep(3)
    FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate only the XML not all hyper links. your locator `//*[@href]` is locating all the HREF links. Use below code

```
#locate all the links which have xml 
allelements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[text()='xml']")

# Iterate all links one by one
for element in allelements:
    element.click()
    class FormPage(object):
        def fill_form(self, data):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-download-reasons-non-commercial').click()")
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-reasons-d-rd').click()")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "name_d"]').send_keys(data['name_d'])
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name = "mail_d"]').send_keys(data['mail_d'])
            return self

        def submit(self):
            driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('edit-submit').click()")


    data = {
        'name_d': 'xyz',
        'mail_d': 'xyz@outlook.com',
    }
    time.sleep(5)
    FormPage().fill_form(data).submit()

    #It opens the download link in new tab So below code again switch back to parent window itself
    window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
    driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
```

Comment: Thank you NarendraR for the response. The runs and after the 1st download I face the following error: 
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of <a class="97081 data-extension xml"> stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed